# Testing OLS Model Prediction Accuracy?

Tags: linear-model, least-squares, accuracy, threshold

How can I test the accuracy of my ordinary least squares model?

Is it a simple comparison between the predicted values of my test set and their actual values (with perhaps a maximum threshold of epsilon -> 0.00001)?

I'm not sure if this is the best approach in terms of accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accuracy as in TP+TN/P+N is used in classification settings; because there you have correct labels and false labels and you want to know how well you are classifying. Since you are using OLS I assume you are in a regression setting. Something like MSE will be better suited I think. Are you in a classification setting with OLS?

Comment: No classification setting :). I have computed the cost after optimization which is 32.072733877455669. Sorry for such a simple question, but using this, how can I test the accuracy on each instance in my testset?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by cost, could you give the formulation for cost? 

if you are in classification, using OLS is not the best practice for various reasons, it is a straight line that goes over 1 and under 0. You could benefit much better by using logistic regression. 

but if you insist on using OLS, treat the values returned by OLS as probabilities, and then choose a cut off threshold, eg 0.5, above which your labels will be 1 and below which they will be 0. Then you can calculate the accuracy, using the above formula.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I'm not in a classification setting, which is why I'm using OLS. I have a straightforward linear regression problem (Predicting house values). I'm using OLS with Batch Gradient Descent (it's a learning exercise, not an actual real-world problem). I know in Logistic Regression you can see whether your model has categorized something correctly by using the formula you mentioned in your answer as a way to test accuracy. I guess my question is what to measure for when testing a dataset against my trained model in OLS for my linear regression problem.

Comment: P.S. By cost I was referring to the computed cost of using theta as the
parameter for linear regression to fit the data points in X and Y. I obtained this by using the Least Squares formula.

Comment: Alright, so you want to measure your models performance on a validation set I suppose. MSE is a good measure, mean squared error:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

you can see it is very similar to the gradient descent cost function. Which is not accidental. Feed your testing X to the model, gather the Y_hats, then compute Y-Y_hat , square it, sum it up and divide by the number of the observations. Just like the Wikipedia page, its a standard measurement for regression problems.